# FileWriter not writing to file at all but not throwing exceptions

Tags: java, filewriter, printwriter, file-writing

I'm attempting to write some text to a file using FileWriter. The program runs without throwing any exceptions except those it's meant to(The writing to file is part of throwing the exception) but the file is left blank. The file is in the same directory as the .java file that contains the exception and the .java file that throws the exception.

I'm flushing and closing the FileWriter object properly, it's in a try/catch block that should be printing any exceptions the code encounters, I've tried using a PrintWriter with the FileWriter as a parameter, and other parts of the method definitely execute.

```java
NegativeBalanceException() throws IOException{
        super("Error:negative balance");
        try {
        FileWriter logger = new FileWriter("logfile.txt", false);
        logger.write("Error:negative balance");
        logger.flush();
        logger.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I expect the file to contain the messages "Amount exceeds balance by -100.0"
and "Error:negative balance". The exception definitely is being created and I can call getMessage() on it to print the two aforementioned messages. However, the file starts blank and remains blank after the program completes.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in what you posted. also, I ran your code locally and it created a file with contents `Error:negative balance`. can you try changing the filename to something else? maybe you have multiple copies of "logfile.txt", your code is writing to one of them and you're viewing another one for validation.

Comment: Are you sure that this code is being called?  Can you add a few unique System.out.println()'s to confirm that it's getting here?  I agree with kaan - this code itself looks fine to me. I think the issue is somewhere else in your test.

Comment: also the location where the **.java** files are is not relevant; more important is in which directory the program is being executed (the working directory) (`System.out.println(new File("logfile.txt").getAbsolutePath())`) Another possibility, some IDEs would copy the (empty) file from the source directory to the generated code directory, overwriting it

Comment: @some if you found the problem all on your own, just by spending some extra time looking at it, then you should delete this question again. You just posted to SO before you were done debugging. Alternatively, don't edit in "I fixed it", but post an answer to this question and then accept that as the answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. I'm working in Eclipse, and it seems that the relative path starts from the program's working directory rather than the src directory as I assumed(and where I placed my file). I was making java look for the file in the wrong place.